# expected curly brace

Tags: apex, class

whats wrong with my code?

```
      public class sample_class{

      List<Account> account_qry = new List<Account>();
      Set<ID> acc_id = new Set<ID>();

 for(Account acc : Trigger.new){
acc_id.add(acc.Id);
}

account_qry = [Select Name FROM Account WHERE Id IN : acc_id];
for (Account acct : Trigger.new){
    if (acct.Name == 'dontDelete'){
    acct.addError('CannotDelete');
    }
}
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two issue with this class

1. You can't write for statement in class it should be inside constructor or inside any method.

   ```
    public class sample_class{

     List<Account> account_qry = new List<Account>();
     Set<ID> acc_id = new Set<ID>();

     public sample_class() {
     for(Account acc : Trigger.new){
       acc_id.add(acc.Id);
    }

   account_qry = [Select Name FROM Account WHERE Id IN : acc_id];
   for (Account acct : Trigger.new){
      if (acct.Name == 'dontDelete'){
       acct.addError('CannotDelete');
      }
     }
    }
   }
   ```
2. second Trigger.new context is available only inside trigger.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I don't see from where are you getting trigger.new. You are not passing this from anywhere and this is not a trigger. I would start by fixing that.